# Is there a better way to create multiple cloudwatch alarms?

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create cloudwatch alarms for some specific load balancers.

What if I have to create 100 cloudwatch alarms, do I need to populate the tfvars the way, I'm updating it currently, or is there any other way which is more optimized.

Following is my code.

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "UnHealthyHosts" {
  for_each = var.cloudwatch_alarms_map

  alarm_name          = each.key                                
  comparison_operator = var.cloudwatch_alarm_operator           
  evaluation_periods  = var.cloudwatch_alarm_evaluation_periods 
  metric_name         = var.cloudwatch_alarm_metric             
  namespace           = each.value["alarm_namespace"]           
  period              = var.cloudwatch_alarm_period             
  statistic           = var.cloudwatch_alarm_statistic          
  threshold           = var.cloudwatch_alarm_threshold          
  alarm_description   = var.cloudwatch_alarm_description        
  actions_enabled     = var.cloudwatch_alarm_actions_enabled    
  alarm_actions       = [aws_sns_topic.sns.arn]                 

  dimensions = {
    TargetGroup  = each.value["target_group_arn"]
    LoadBalancer = each.value["load_balancer_arn"]
  }
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "cloudwatch_alarms_map" {
  type = map(object({
    alarm_namespace          = string # eg: AWS/ApplicationELB
    target_group_arn  = string
    load_balancer_arn = string
  }))
  default     = {}
}
```

**terraform.tfvars**

```
cloudwatch_alarms_map = {
    app1-unhealthy-alarm = {
      target_group_arn_suffix  = "targetgroup/sample-app1-tg/12de123e123123aa"
      load_balancer_arn_suffix = "app/sample-alb-app1-lb/12c5732bd012e47a"
      alarm_namespace          = "AWS/ApplicationELB"
    }
    app2-unhealthy-alarm = {
      target_group_arn_suffix  = "targetgroup/sample-app2-tg/313e7f1ad4a2e373"
      load_balancer_arn_suffix = "app/sample-alb-app2-lb/f2c5132bd012e47a"
      alarm_namespace          = "AWS/ApplicationELB"
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the ALBs?

Comment: If you *know* you'll have 100 alarms to configure, I would go with creating a module and providing sane defaults when/if you don't want to set all of the values you are setting now.

Comment: @jordanm - some of the alb's are created using terraform, some of them where created long back before we started using terraform.

Comment: @MarkoE - the main.tf is actually a module, what i want to know is how can i provide multiple cloudwatch alarms in a more optimized way. Right now with the tfvars i'm populating all the 100+ names with respective target group and load balancer arn's. is there a better way ?

Comment: If that is the case about ALBs, are those a part of the same module or not? Also, there is nothing stopping you from importing those ALBs that were created manually/some other way to Terraform.